# Is switching between multiple Program3D's during ENTER_FRAME computationally expensive?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, shader, stage3d

When setting up a `Stage3D`'s `Context3D` for rendering, is it expensive / bad practice to switch between `Program3D`'s in an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` cycle?

I don't have an example at hand, but I'm curious to know if there's such situations where this alternation between programs would be used and if the frame-rate would suffer considerably.

Answer (score 3):

There is some cost associated with it, but I don't think I'd call it expensive. Of course, if you have more than one shader in your scene, you're going to have to switch between Program3Ds every frame - you just wouldn't want to do that more than necessary. So, the solution is to render all the meshes for a particular shader, then move on to the next shader, etc.